# Prove $\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,-1)} f(x,y)=1$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be defined by $f(x,y)= 3x + 2y$.
>
> Prove that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,-1)} f(x,y)=1$$

I know that I must prove that for every $\epsilon>0$ we can find a $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x,y) - 1| < \epsilon$ whenever $0< || (x,y) - (1,-1)|| < \delta$.

I am not sure how to choose my $\delta$ though?

Comment: You can always start with $\delta = \epsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hint***:
\begin{align}
& |f(x, y) - 1| \\
= & |3x + 2y - (3 - 2)| \\
= & |3(x - 1) + 2(y - (-1)| \\
\leq & 3|x - 1| + 2|y - (-1)| \\
\leq & 3\left[|x - 1| + |y - (-1)|\right]
\end{align}
Now use the inequality 
$$|x - 1| + |y - (-1)| \leq \sqrt{(x - 1)^2 + (y - (-1))^2} = \|(x, y) - (1, -1)\|$$

Comment: Thank you!! :). So I must choose $\delta = \frac{ \epsilon}{3}$ ? :)

Comment: Yes, why not?:)

Comment: Will $\delta = \epsilon$ also work? :)

Comment: @DJS You can choose any 0<$\delta\le\epsilon/3$.

Comment: @DJS Choosing either $\delta = \varepsilon$ or $\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ is OK, the difference is not essential. Of course, if you want to perfectly match the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition, choose $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ would look prettier.